# RoboGuice 2.0 and Robolectric 1.1 Testing RoboAsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, junit, roboguice, robolectric

I am currently using both RoboGuice 2.0 and Robolectric 1.1 in my Android application.  I've noticed that the RoboLooperThread is gone in 2.0 and I'm having difficulties having any RoboAsyncTask's be invoked.  When the main test thread calls `.execute()` on the `RoboAsyncTask`, the RoboAsyncTask's `call()` method is never called.  My question is how can I force the test thread to switch to and from the UI thread so that way the task can be executed?

Thanks,

Vince

Answer (score 3):

I've found a working solution.  The `RoboAsyncTask` appears to be put on Robolectric's `UiThreadScheduler` and can be invoked via `Robolectric.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();`